# Excel VBA user double clicks cell from anywhere

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Excel 2010 and have a range of codes in column A.  When a user double clicks one, it copy the value of whatever it is to cell A2 using the below code on the BeforeDoubleClick event of the worksheet - this works fine:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A4:A100000")) Is Nothing Then Cancel = True
Target.Copy Destination:=Sheets("GL Codes").Range("A2")
```

The problem is, if they click the description in column B it doesn't copy the respective value from column A - how do I do this?

In summary, no matter where in the row the user double clicks, the cell value from column A needs to be copied to A2 - is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both copy and paste are "GL Codes" sheet, where this code lies, you don't need to reference it in your code.

Also, since you want to enter this code, wherever someone clicks in rows 1-100000, you don't need to use the `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A4:A100000")) Is Nothing` line.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

' copy the row in Column A of the cell you double-clicked to A2
Range("A" & Target.Row).Copy Destination:=Range("A2")

End Sub
```

Comment: Was going to write the exact same code.  Was thinking of adding `Cancel = TRUE` so the double-click doesn't place the cursor in the cell for editing.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook feel free to edit my code if it improves the answer

Answer (score -1):

You are checking on `Range("A4:A100000")`.
If you want to work on A and B, change it to `Range("A4:B100000")`, and likewhise for any column index.

Comment: changing the range to include B then copies the description from B to A2 when you double click the description, which is no good